# search in firestore swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to apply search in my app but it shows a random product not the same of what I'm typing at searchBar

method :

```
    static func getSearch ( name : String ,completion : @escaping (_ product : ProductObject) ->  ()) {
        
        
        let path = Firestore.firestore().collection("Products").whereField("name" , isLessThanOrEqualTo: name)
        path.addSnapshotListener { (query, error) in
            if error != nil {return}
            guard let doucments = query?.documents else {return}
            for doc in doucments {
                
                if let data = doc.data() as [String: AnyObject]? {
                    let newData = ProductObject(dictionary: data)
                    completion (newData)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

at searchBar text did change :

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        
        self.products = []
        ProductApi.getSearch(name: searchText) { (pro) in
            self.products.append(pro)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        if searchTxt.text?.count == 0  {
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { searchBar.resignFirstResponder() }
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

this was the best way I found :

let path = Firestore.firestore().collection("Products").order(by: "name").start(at: [name]).end(at: ["(name) \u{f8ff}"])